# Include records occurring within a date period

Tags: sql, vba, date, criteriaquery

50 records in databank.  I prepared a query to select contracts with ending dates between 1/1/2019 and 12/31/2020.  Some of the records have dates outside the 12/31/2020; 12/31/2021.  I want those records included as they were active during the queried period.

The between query only returns records with the ending date of 12/31/2020.  I changed the criteria to end period between 1/1/2019 and 12/31/2021 and not 12/31/2022. That returns records before end end date of 12/31/20 and outside the start of the end period of 1/1/2019.

I've tried about 10 other things (can't remember all of them) regardless am not getting the results I need.

I'm not VBA/SQL friendly, I'm a query kind of user.  Sorry if that makes my question a little more difficult.

Thank you soooo much for any direction you can give me!!

Answer (score 0):

```
select *, DATE_FORMAT(*datetime_column*,'%m/%d/%Y') from *table_name* where *datetime_column* between '1/1/2019' and '12/31/2020'
```

I think the format of date leads to 'query don't satisfy correct result' problem. You could convert the date to this format and check the result